# Multi animation?

Tags: animation

My problem is when I want to add new animation to my project. I find both animation interrupted. Some time it changes it places. this one example when only change frames. Please explain step by step.
[image]
[image]

Comment: I'm sorry but I cannot understand your question. Could you be more specific?

Comment: These images show you strange issue i faced when i want to make multi animation. My question is how to make multi animation correctly ?

Comment: Ok! That's what you asked, but i'm sorry, looking at the images I don't understand which are the issues you face...

Comment: Man, in the second image I didn't change the position of the sphere. If I done from the first animation, and start with the second one. some objects change it position when I change the frame value. Why ? I don't know.

Comment: Ok!
Wich way are you making "multi-animation"? Just creating more "actions" in the Dope Sheet Editor or do you do something also in the NLA Editor?

Comment: Just _creating more "actions" in the Dope Sheet Editor_ for two objects. first action both objects moving together. second action, both goes far and get close. third action........ and so on.

Comment: Ok! Sorry for all the questions :-) Just wanted some info in order to understand. I'm sorry but I can't figure out what's happening. Could you attach a .blend file?